# Receive on UDP socket and send reply

Tags: android, sockets

I am working on a client/server project, the client being Android and the server being C#.

What I am trying to do is the Android app listens on a UDP socket and the C# server sends a message on that port. Android will then receive the message from the reply, and send back a response.

This is the code I have:

```
public void run()
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Heartbeat manager thread starting");
        try
        {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
            DatagramSocket socket = new DatagramSocket(HEARTBEAT_PORT);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);

            while (!cancelThread)
            {
                socket.receive(packet);

                final String xml = new String(packet.getData(), 0, packet.getLength());

                Log.v(TAG, xml);

                XmlSettings xmlSettings = new XmlSettings();
                xmlSettings.setIndent(true);
                XmlWriter writer = new XmlWriter(xmlSettings);

                writer.writeStartDocument();
                writer.writeStartElement("HeartbeatManager");
                writer.writeElementString("Command", Defines.ServerCommands.HeartbeatResponse.toString());
                writer.writeEndElement();

                buffer = writer.returnXmlOutput().getBytes();

                DatagramPacket replyPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
                socket.send(replyPacket);
            }
        }
        catch (SocketException ex)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Socket Exception Occurred: " + ex.toString());
        }
        catch (IOException ex)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "IOException Occurred: " + ex.toString());
        }
```

At the moment it throws an exception when I do the socket.send stating that the destination address is null.

Comment: Side note I think your definition of "server" is by size of the device... Usually whoever listens for incoming requests ("Android app listens on a UDP socket") is called "server"...

Comment: I'm calling C# the server as it is the one doing most of the work, more often that not it does the listening, however, for this part of the project I need android to listen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set the destination address in the DatagramPacket before sending it.

The constructor you're using (without the address) is just for receiving, not for sending.

In UDP protocol, destination is set in the packet because there is not a connection (like TCP)
So in your code you are telling the socket, which has no concecpt of destination to send a packet without destination, so it'll throw and exception.

```
InetSocketAddress address = InetSocketAddress("www.google.com", 8080);
DatagramPacket replyPacket = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length, address); 
socket.send(replyPacket);
```

Comment: The easy way to to that is to reuse the received DatagramPacket, which already has the source address, and just change the data and send it.